# Using Anonymous method not preferred by .NET itself?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, anonymous-function

```
I am trying to learn the anonymous method and tried out this sample.
```

So, whenever I am trying to call WriteLog function i can just use

```
()=> { return "someLogData" };
```

The advantage is that, I need not have a separate function and can save lines of code.

```
    public void WriteLog(Func<string> s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

But, the same does not work out with functions like

```
Console.WriteLine( ()=> {return "someString" } );
```

Why does .NET provide this anonymous method functionality but does not let to use it in one of its own kind?

Comment: because it's not really necessary.

Comment: if there are thousands of people like you, I think we need thousands of overloads of `Console.WriteLine`. Remember that `Console.Write` is just used to output some string in `Console` window.

Comment: @KingKing: makes sense.. as somebody said, follow "KISS" principle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no overloads of `Console.WriteLine` which accept a `Func<string>` - and indeed even your current `WriteLog` method won't do anything *useful* (as you'd need to invoke the delegate).

Where methods accepting specific delegates *do* exist - most prominently in LINQ, but elsewhere too - you can indeed use lambda expressions or anonymous methods to invoke them.

You *can* call `Console.WriteLine` using a lambda expression, but you need to cast it to a specific delegate type - as there are only conversions from lambda expressions to specific delegate or expression types, not just `Delegate` or `object`. So this will work:

```
Console.WriteLine((Func<string>)(() => "someLogData"));
```

Again though, it wouldn't be useful to do so anyway - you don't want to log the delegate, you want to log the result of *invoking* the delegate.

It doesn't make *very* much sense for `Console.WriteLine` to accept delegates IMO, but it would make more sense for more flexible logging, where you don't want to evaluate the string unless you're actually going to write it to a log.

Note that your `WriteLog` call itself can be simpler too:

```
WriteLog(() => "someLogData");
```

Comment: Thanks jon. but why do you say that WriteLog method is not useful ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: Currently you're printing out the delegate itself, which won't print out the string.

Comment: @JonSkeet: In the first line :  "and indeed even your current WriteLog method won't do useful"!

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: Have you tried calling it as written? What was the result? (It wouldn't be `someLogData`...)

Comment: my bad! sorry, I didn read the line after that. I should invoke the delegate! thanks for the great comments.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have your anonymous method executed to get the string.

```
public void WriteLog(Func<string> s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an advantage in this form:

```
public void WriteLog(Func<string> s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

let's imagine that inside it it's written as:

```
public void WriteLog(Func<string> s)
{
    if (needToWriteLog)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

now, let's say that you call it this way:

```
WriteLog(() => StringThatNeedsFiveSecondsToBuild())
```

and let's compare it to a similar WriteLog that only accepts a `string` as a parameter:

```
WriteLog(StringThatNeedsFiveSecondsToBuild())
```

The second `WriteLog` will always spend 5 seconds to build the string, even when `needToWriteLog` is `false`, while the first one will build it only if it's `true`.

Now, compare it to `Console.WriteLine`: `Console.WriteLine` will always print its content, so there is no need to use a delegate, because the 5 seconds will always be spent.

There are some methods that are similar in C#, the ones of the family `Debug.*` and `Trace.*`, but they are different. You use them like this:

```
Debug.WriteLine(StringThatNeedsFiveSecondsToBuild())
```

the trick is that they are defined like this:

```
[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]
public static void WriteLine(string value)
```

so that if the `DEBUG` isn't defined, the whole `Debug.WriteLine(StringThatNeedsFiveSecondsToBuild())` is removed, even if it had some side effects (like spending 5 seconds :-) )

All of this show something else: it's VERY important that the delegates you pass to your `WriteLog` AND the parameters you pass to the `Debug.*` and `Assert.*` be side effect free (clearly ignoring the time as a side effect, I mean "real" side effects like changing variable values), because you don't know if they'll really be executed.